# Calendar Issues while traveling

Tags: ios, mac, icloud, calendar

When traveling the calendar shows my appointments in local time, where I am at the moment. If I'm in Tokyo, for example, my 8 PM appointment next week in St Paul will show up as 5 AM. The settings are not the same for Mac and iOS, and there seems to be no way to globally force these applications to simply act as a paper calendar would, nor can I find any apps that will do that. It's crazy, frustrating and incomprehensible. I certainly understand why some people need that feature, but with computers this powerful those of us who don't need an option. This issue has been going on for years. I've dealt with any number of Apple support people both on the phone and at Genius Bars, and there's simply no way to get this to work.

On the Mac, there's a feature called "floating" which does that, but it has to be engaged for each appointment that I make, and it doesn't exist on iOS, so if I make an appointment on my phone I can't do that...

The question is, is there ANYTHING out there that can work as a simple paper calendar? Set it and forget it, what you put in is what you get. If I haven't explained myself clearly, I just want to ignore time zones completely, deal with absolute times.

Comment: So are you asking in essence if you can enter calendar entries as UTC going forward or how to convert time zones or perhaps to ignore when the computer locale shifts?

Answer (score 1):

Most third party calendar tools on iOS offer this. I can really recommend fantastical, which offers the option you're looking for. See [this](https://flexibits.com/fantastical-iphone/help/settings) site.

> Time Zone Override: When enabled, Fantastical will always show dates and times in the selected time zone. When disabled, Fantastical 2 will use the time zone configured in iOS's Settings app. This option is useful if you are traveling but still want to see your schedule in your home time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to another calendar app if you wish, but you can continue using the iOS Calendar app since Time Zone Override is a function of iOS Settings.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear. I don't want the times I see to change. EVER. I want nothing to do with time zones on the calendar. I want it OFF. I want to be able to look at it as if it were a paper calendar. That's the way I work, and frankly, it's very hard for me to understand why that cannot be done.

Comment: Understood.  I'm almost certain that if Time Zone Override is always ON, they won't change.